# WCF Web API Test Client thinks it's on a different port?

Tags: azure, wcf-web-api

When I try to access my WCF Web API Test Client through the browser it thinks that it's running on port 84 instead of 83 (I'm running in the Azure Development Fabric).  It changes the URL to "http://machinename:84" instead of "http://localhost:83".  Since nothing is listening on port 84, it obviously doesn't work.

Comment: I've spent the last 24 hours trying to find a solution to this problem.  I thought I was going mad!  For me it only seems to be POST requests, GET requests seem to go to the right port, but post requests get sent to a port which is one number higher (i.e. the application is on port 8080 which is where GET requests go to, but POST requests get redirected to port 8081).  I've tried specifying the port in the config file but to no avail.  Looks like an issue with the Azure emulator.  
What's the reference number for the bug you raised?  I'd like to track it and any responses.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should file an issue:
http://wcf.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: Done.  I was hoping that maybe it wasn't a bug and I was doing something silly causing this problem.